# How do I show branches only inside one branch folder or subfolder?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-branch-sculpting

I have organized my branches into folders and subfolders. I am only accessing my GIT repo through the CLI. I would like to be able to list only branches inside a branch folder.

> FEATURE/branch-1
>   FEATURE/branch-2
>   FEATURE/CURRENT/branch-000
>   FEATURE/CURRENT/branch-001
>   FEATURE/CURRENT/branch-002
>   *** master**
>   dev
>   v2.0.0/branch-3
>   v2.1.0/branch-4
>   v2.1.0/branch-5

`> git branch` shows me everything, however I would like to only see the **v2.1.0** folder. Is there a command that can output only the **v2.1.0** branch folder from my example above?

Also, as a bonus, is there a way to get a branch subfolder `FEATURE/CURRENT/**`?

Comment: Side note to *all* the answers below: if you're using a Unix style shell, you may need to quote the asterisk in some circumstances, e.g., `git branch --list 'v2.1.0/*'`. This occurs when there's also a *file* that matches the pattern: the shell will expand the `*` before Git ever has a chance to use it for branch names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git branch --list *v2.1.0*` will show all branches with v2.1.0 in their branch name

Comment: This answer is nice. I like the simplicity of the output and I may add that I can reduce this by one more character `git branch --list v2.1.0*`

Comment: Now that I played with this and accepted the answer, I'd like to now see if there's a **not** command. so look for all ** v2.1.0* ** but not *TEST*

Comment: You could pipe it into grep. Not sure how to do NOT within the git branch command. `git branch --list v2.1.0* | grep -iv test` The 'v' negates the grep and the 'i' makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [git show branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch) is what you're looking for. You can use globs and everything.

For instance, if you've got `master`, `b/one` and `b/two`

```
git show-branch b/*
```

will show

```
! [b/one] Some changes
 ! [b/two] changed to kk2
--
 + [b/two] changed to kk2
++ [b/one] Some changes
```

There's a bit of stuff (like the last commit) besides the branch name, but that will *only* list the branches you are looking for.

Comment: Great link, but this shows me an exhaustive list of commits whereas I'm trying to quickly see what branches are inside one branch folder. git show branch shows commits, which I am not looking for.

Comment: If I can see an example what <pattern> would look like. I also do not need to see what is in the remote repository.

Comment: `git branch --list *OBE*` will show all branches with OBE in their branch name

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`git branch -a --list v2.1.0/*`

I think it will solve your problem